# Show the equivalence of two logic propositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have 2 logic propositions:

C v ( A -> B)

(C v A) -> (C v B)

I'm trying to show that these 2 are equivalent (if it's possible) but I'm stuck halfway.

Here's my attempt.

For C v (A -> B)

= C v (~A v B) **by x -> y = ~x v y**

= (~A v B) v C **by commutative law**

---

For (C v A) -> (C v B)

= ~(C v A) v (C v B) **by x -> y = ~x v y**

= (~C^~A) v (C v B) **by de morgan's law**

= (~A^~C) v (C v B) **by commutative law**

For the last sentence here, can I do anything with ~C v C?

Answer (score 0):

Try the distributive law. To answer your last question: $\neg C \vee C$ is always true.
 Another easy approach would be by checking cases $C = 0$ and $C = 1$. In the latter case both sentences are always true. For $C=0$ note that $0 \vee A$ is equivalent to $A$ for every sentence $A$.